# React custom hook: Test a custom hook that returns a function expecting a mousedown event as a parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a react custom hook used in a component that returns two things (an object and a function) as shown in the code.

More details:

- the object is of the type {x: number, y:number}
- the function however expects (e: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>)

```
  export const usePan = (): [IPoint, (e: SyntheticMouseEvent) => void] => {
  const [panState, setPanState] = useState<IPoint>(PAN_ORIGIN);
  const lastPointRef = useRef<IPoint>(PAN_ORIGIN);

  ...
  
  ...

  const startPan = useCallback(
    (e: SyntheticMouseEvent) => {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", pan);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", endPan);
      lastPointRef.current = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
    },
    [pan, endPan]
  );

  return [panState, startPan];
};
```

The custom hook is then called in the component as shown below:

```
export default function CanvasProvider(props: PropsWithChildren<unknown>) {
  const [offset, startPan] = usePan();

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={(e) => startPan(e)}
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        background: "#EBEBEB",
      }}
      data-testid="canvas-wrapper"
    >
      <CanvasComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the test:

```
  test("should pan on mousedown", () => {
    renderApp();
    const canvas = screen.getByTestId(/canvas-wrapper/i);
    fireEvent.mouseDown(canvas);
    const { result } = renderHook(() => usePan());
    result.current[1](); //this is where the error is as the function requires a mousedown event as params
    expect(result.current[0].x).not.toEqual(0);
    expect(result.current[0].y).not.toEqual(0);
  });
```

I will add more details as necessary. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would have thought you wanted to render your hook before firing events.

Comment: @possum I did that also. But I still need to pass an event into result.current[1](//event here) which is the main issue. Perhaps there is an entirely different way to write the test? I'm kind of blank here.